# Restore source code Angular after deployment

Tags: angular

I deleted the angular source code.
how to restore source code after deployed.

Info :
I use angular 12.
Product deploy project

thank.

Comment: What exactly did you delete? you can always install angular again....

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ngrev](https://github.com/mgechev/ngrev), a project from one of the Angular product leads. It's a graphical tool to see the structure of your project.

Besides this, there is now way to restore your projects source code / project.